# How to add a new root suffix entry in openldap?

Tags: openldap

I try to add new root suffix in openldap following this guide [Creating_and_Maintaining_Suffixes](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/CDS/ag/8.0/Configuring_Directory_Databases-Creating_and_Maintaining_Suffixes.html), but I got the error :

`ldap_add: Invalid syntax (21)
    additional info: objectclass: value #2 invalid per syntax`

I just can't find which schema I have lost for objectClass.

Comment: Please add information stating exactly what you do, down to pasting your ldif files when appropriate. Please read [How to ask better questions on Serverfault](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault).

Comment: And also: Are you aware that the guide you are referring to deals with Red Hat Directory Server (also known as 389 DS) which is an entirely different product then OpenLDAP?